# rel="next" in anchor tag is not working

Tags: google-search-console, rel, pagination

I have 100's of duplicate meta description issue in google webmaster tool because of the pagination. Pagination pages are showing as  duplicate in tool. So I added the `rel="next"` and `rel="prev"` to the pagination link anchor tags. But it seems like not working.

I red the [Google office webmaster blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html). That never mentioned to add anchor tag to the rel attributes. So should only adding rel attribute with link work or it will work with anchor tag as well.

example :

```
 <link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=2" />
```

I red few unofficial blogs that mentioned the it will work with anchor. So please can anyone tell what I am doing here wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Using rel prev and rel next isn't going to solve the duplicate title and meta description problem.  Several people on Google's blog post that it doesn't prevent these errors in Webmaster Tools.  For example:

> cynthiacoffield said...
>   I've had similar duplicate title tag issues that are resolved with rel prev/next canonical.

I would recommend putting the page number into the title and meta description for pages 2+

- Page 1: Widgets for sale
- Page 2: Widgets for sale (page 2)
- Page 3: Widgets for sale (page 3)

Answer (score -1):

It should help. There is Google's official guide

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html

Comment: I red that post and I mentioned in my question as well. My question is rel attribute with value next/prev will work in anchor or not?

Comment: As I know, it should work only in header.